# Graphics.MeasureString() - Finding the relative X,Y coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

I am attempting to create a custom `ListBox` control in WinForms.

I have subclassed it, set `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`, and am overriding `OnDrawItem`.  I have created a custom `ColoredListBoxItem` class that has additional properties to deal with the highlighting.

This is all fine.  My issue is that this functionality needs to highlight words within the text of a list item.

Here is as far as I've gotten, and it doesn't work, because the X coordinate of the highlight remains constant and does not correspond to the actual X coordinate of the text.

How can I get a `Point` value (or `Rectangle`) to use with `DrawText` that will overlay the highlighted text?  I've tried doing some math with the bounds of the original text `Rectangle` versus the highlight `Rectangle` but it is not working as expected.

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e) {

    ColoredListBoxItem item = this.Items[e.Index] as ColoredListBoxItem;

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    Rectangle fullMessageRect = e.Bounds;

    // Draw the original, full text
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item.Message, e.Font, 
          new Point(fullMessageRect.X, fullMessageRect.Y), 
          this.ForeColor);

    // Check if we have any text to be highlighted
    if (SomethingToHighlight(item)) {

        // Find the text to highlight, and get its area
        SizeF highlightedAreaSize = 
              e.Graphics.MeasureString(item.TextToHightlight, e.Font);

        PointF highlightAreaPoint = highlightedAreaSize.ToPointF();

        Point point = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(highlightAreaPoint.X),
             Convert.ToInt32(fullMessageRect.Y));

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item.TextToHightlight, e.Font, 
             point, this.ForeColor, item.HighlightColor);

    }

}
```

Here is what I'm seeing in a demo app, where the output just shows work being done, and I am trying to highlight one particular word .. in this case "height".

[image: Sample debugging output]

Don't pay any attention to the actual output, it's a bunch of nonsense so I can see exactly how another part of the system is adjusting `PictureBox` images on the fly.

Lines that it thinks should be highlighted are shown twice, once in the original format and then again with the highlight applied.  Notice how the highlighted part is correct in the Y coordinate, but does not change in the X.

Here's what I am seeing in the Watch window when I set a break point prior to writing the highlighted text:

[image: Watch window]

Clearly, I don't need the variable `highlightAreaPoint`, because it's the same as `highlightedAreaSize`.

Probably something obvious here but I'm tired of fiddling with it at this point!

Comment: Seems like you are measuring the string to hightlight and then taking that width and starting the highlight from there not taking into account where that word actually starts in the sentence? You need to do a measure string of all the words before it to know where the highlighted word starts and then you can write out the highlighted word.

Comment: @FSDaniel Yep.  I get the general idea.  But what are the code modifications required here to get the proper overlay area?  In this test case I'm only dealing with highlighting one found word but eventually I need to get all of them.  What needs to be changed with what I currently have in order for it to know the top-left X,Y coordinates to place the drawn text?  Am I missing an API here?  I am "measuring the string of all the words".  That's stored in the `fullMessageRect` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can feel your pain as I have been there before. Actually, I wanted to design my own Textbox not inheriting from Microsoft.Textbox control and when I researched on-line, I sort of discouraged to learn 1000 reasons why one must not reinvent the wheel and why it is so difficult to do from scratch. Highlighting selection text was one of the major challenge among the others like right-to-left, caret positioning, non-fixed fonts etc. But I decided to fly against the wind because I had my reasons to do so and finally got what I wanted. Since my text selection code was for TextBox, I had to change it to suit your requirement as you are dealing with ListBox.

Following is the code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HowToHighlightPortionOfText
{
    public static class Helper
    {
        private static Rectangle dummy
        {
            get
            {
                return new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
            }
        }
        const uint H = 0x00000000;
        const uint V = 0x00000001;
        const uint T = 0x00000002;

        #region api functions
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int DrawText(IntPtr hdc, string lpStr, int nCount, ref Dimension lpRect, int wFormat);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(this IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteObject(this IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "GdiGradientFill", ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern bool GradientFill(IntPtr hdc, Trivertex[] pVertex,
            uint dwNumVertex, uint[] pMesh, uint dwNumMesh, uint dwMode);

        [DllImport("gdi32")]
        public static extern int SetBkMode(this IntPtr hdc, int nBkMode);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern uint SetTextColor(this IntPtr hdc, int crColor);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern uint SetBkColor(this IntPtr hdc, int crColor);
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        //use this function to hilight portion of listbox item text
        public static void HilightItemText(this ListBox control, int itemIndex, int startIndex, int endIndex,
             Color highlightForeColor, Color highlightBackColorStart,  Color? highlightBackColorEnd = null)
        {
            var container = control.GetItemRectangle(itemIndex);
            var text = control.GetItemText(itemIndex);

            using (Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics())
            {
                g.HighlightText(control.Font, text, container, startIndex, endIndex,
                    highlightForeColor, highlightBackColorStart, highlightBackColorEnd);

            }
        }

        public static void HighlightText(this IDeviceContext dc, Font font, string text,
           Rectangle container, int start, int end, Color highlightForeColor, Color highlightBackColorStart, 
           Color? highlightBackColorEnd, DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            IntPtr hdc = dc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr _font = SelectObject(hdc, font.ToHfont());

            Dimension dm = container;
            var flag = flags.getMeasureFlag(false);

            SetBkMode(hdc, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Transparent));

            //first draw whole text
            DrawText(hdc, text, text.Length, ref dm, 0);

            //now get the highlight rectangle which will draw the highlighted text
            Rectangle textBound, uptoIndex;
            var rect = hdc.rangeBound(text, container, start, end, out textBound, out uptoIndex, flags: flags);
            dm = rect;

            var _backColorEnd = highlightBackColorEnd ?? highlightBackColorStart;
            hdc.Fill(rect, highlightBackColorStart, _backColorEnd, Angle.A0);

            SetTextColor(hdc, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(highlightForeColor));

            if (start < 0 || start > text.Length - 1 || end < 0 || end > text.Length - 1)
                throw new Exception("start and end value must be with in text length");

            var _text = text.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
            DrawText(hdc, _text, _text.Length, ref dm, 0);

            DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, _font));
            dc.ReleaseHdc();
        }

        public static Rectangle RangeBound(this IDeviceContext dc, Font font, string text,
           Rectangle container, int start, int end, DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            Rectangle textBound, uptoIndex;
            return dc.RangeBound(font, text, container, start, end, out textBound, out uptoIndex, flags);
        }

        public static Rectangle GetPortionRectangleToHighlight(this ListBox control, int itemIndex, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            var container = control.GetItemRectangle(itemIndex);
            var text = control.GetItemText(itemIndex);
            Rectangle rect;

            using (Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics())
            {
                rect = g.RangeBound(control.Font, text, container, startIndex, endIndex);

            }
            return rect;
        }

        public static bool Fill(this IntPtr hdc, Rectangle rc, Color c1,
           Color c2, Angle angle)
        {
            return hdc.Fill(rc.X, rc.Y, rc.Right, rc.Bottom, c1, c2, angle);
        }

        public static bool Fill(this IntPtr hdc, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, Color c1, Color c2, Angle angle)
        {
            Trivertex[] t = new Trivertex[4]
            {
                new Trivertex(x0, y0, c1),
                new Trivertex(x1, y1, c2),
                new Trivertex(x0, y1, c1, c2),
                new Trivertex(x1, y0, c1, c2)
            };
            uint[] pMesh = new uint[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3 };

            switch ((int)angle % 180)
            {
                case 0:
                    return GradientFill(hdc, t, 2, pMesh, 1, H);
                case 45:
                    return GradientFill(hdc, t, 4, pMesh, 2, T);
                case 90:
                    return GradientFill(hdc, t, 2, pMesh, 1, V);
                case 135:
                    t[0].x = x1;
                    t[3].x = x0;
                    t[1].x = x0;
                    t[2].x = x1;
                    return GradientFill(hdc, t, 4, pMesh, 2, T);
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region get the highlight rectangle
        static Rectangle RangeBound(this IDeviceContext dc, Font font, string text,
            Rectangle container, int start, int end, out Rectangle textBound, out Rectangle uptoIndex, DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            textBound = Rectangle.Empty;
            uptoIndex = Rectangle.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return Rectangle.Empty;

            IntPtr hdc = dc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr _font = SelectObject(hdc, font.ToHfont());

            var rc = hdc.rangeBound(text, container, start, end, out textBound, out uptoIndex, flags: flags);

            DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, _font));
            dc.ReleaseHdc();
            return rc;
        }

        static TextMeasurement charRectangle(this IntPtr hdc, string text, Rectangle container,
            string wholeText = null, Point? point = null, bool adjustByPoint = false, DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return TextMeasurement.Default;

            TextMeasurement measurement = new TextMeasurement();
            Rectangle textBound;

            wholeText = (wholeText ?? text);

            var location = container.Location;

            var measureWholeText = point == null;
            measurement.UserPoint = point ?? Point.Empty;


            textBound = hdc.textBound(wholeText, container, flags: flags);

            var rect = textBound;
            var p = point ?? new Point(container.Right, container.Y);

            if (!measureWholeText)
            {
                if (p.X > textBound.Right)
                    p.X = textBound.Right;
                else if (p.X < textBound.Left)
                    p.X = textBound.X;
            }

            var charIndex = 0;

            var result = hdc.charRectangle(text, ref p, rect, flags, measureWholeText);

            charIndex = Math.Max(0, result.Item2);
            var rectangles = result.Item1;

            measurement.Bounds = rectangles[0];
            measurement.TextBounds = (measureWholeText) ? rectangles[1] : textBound;
            rectangles[1] = measurement.TextBounds;

            if (!measureWholeText && adjustByPoint && charIndex > 0)
            {
                float middle = (float)measurement.Bounds.Left +
                    measurement.Bounds.Width / 2;
                if (p.X > middle - 1)
                {
                    Rectangle r;
                    Dimension r1 = measurement.TextBounds;

                    var newresult = hdc.charBound(text, charIndex + 2, ref r1,
                        (int)flags.getMeasureFlag(false), out r);

                    if (!newresult.Equals(measurement.Bounds) &&
                        newresult.X > measurement.Bounds.X)
                    {
                        charIndex++;
                        measurement.Bounds = newresult;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (measurement.Bounds.Size.Width<=0)
                measurement.Bounds = new Rectangle(measurement.Bounds.Location, new Size(2, 2));

            measurement.CharIndex = charIndex;
            measurement.Char = '\0';
            measurement.Char = text[Math.Min(charIndex, text.Length - 1)];
            return measurement;
        }

        static Tuple<Rectangle[], int> charRectangle(this IntPtr hdc, string text, ref Point p, Rectangle rect,
             DrawTextFlags? flags, bool measureWholeText = false)
        {
            int i = 0;

            int middle = text.Length / 2, start = 0;
            bool first = true;
            do
            {
                var upto = hdc.Measure(text.Substring(0, middle), null, rect, flags);
                bool found = upto.Has(p);
                if (!found)
                {
                    start = middle;
                    middle += (text.Length - middle) / 2;
                    first = false;
                    if (start == middle) break;
                }
                else break;
            } while (middle > 1 && text.Length - middle > 1);

            if (first)
            {
                return hdc.charRectangle(text.Substring(0, middle),
                    ref p, rect, flags);
            }
            else
            {
                Rectangle[] list = new Rectangle[2];
                for (i = start; i <= middle; i++)
                {
                    if (hdc.Measure(text, out list, p, i + 1, rect, flags))
                        break;
                }
                i = Math.Max(i, 0);
                return new Tuple<Rectangle[], int>(list, i);
            }
        }

        static Rectangle charBound(this IntPtr hdc, string text, int len,
           ref Dimension bounds, int flag, out Rectangle whole)
        {
            DrawText(hdc, text, len, ref bounds, flag);
            whole = bounds;
            var rc = bounds;
            if (len - 1 > 0 && len <= text.Length)
            {
                DrawText(hdc, text.Substring(0, len - 1), len - 1, ref rc, flag);
                rc = Rectangle.FromLTRB(rc.Right, bounds.Top, bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom);
            }
            return rc;
        }

       static Rectangle rangeBound(this IntPtr hdc, string text, Rectangle container, int start, int end,
            out Rectangle textBound, out Rectangle uptoIndex,   DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            textBound = Rectangle.Empty;
            uptoIndex = Rectangle.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return Rectangle.Empty;

            var location = container.Location;
            textBound = hdc.textBound(text, container, flags);

            Dimension rect = textBound;
            var flag = flags.getMeasureFlag(false);

            start++;
            var text1 = text.Substring(0, start);
            var rc = hdc.charBound(text1, text1.Length, ref rect, (int)flag, out uptoIndex);

            end++;
            var text2 = text.Substring(0, end);
            DrawText(hdc, text2, text2.Length, ref rect, (int)flag);

            return Rectangle.FromLTRB(rc.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
        }

        static Rectangle textBound(this IntPtr hdc, string text, Rectangle container,  DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            Rectangle rc = Rectangle.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return rc;
            Point p = container.Location;

            var r = hdc.Measure(text, text.Length, flags: flags);
            return new Rectangle(p, r.Size);
        }


        static DrawTextFlags getMeasureFlag(this DrawTextFlags? flags, bool textboxControl = false)
        {
            DrawTextFlags flag = DrawTextFlags.CalculateArea;
            if (flags != null) flag |= flags.Value;

            flag |= DrawTextFlags.WordBreak | DrawTextFlags.NoPrefix
                | DrawTextFlags.NoPadding | DrawTextFlags.NoClipping;

            if (textboxControl) flag |= DrawTextFlags.TextBoxControl;
            else flag |= DrawTextFlags.SingleLine;
            return flag;
        }

        static Rectangle RangeBound(this IntPtr hdc, string text,
           Rectangle container, int start, int end, DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            Rectangle textBound, uptoIndex;
            return hdc.rangeBound(text, container, start, end, out textBound, out uptoIndex, flags);
        }

        static Rectangle Measure(this IntPtr hdc, string text, int? length = null,
           Rectangle? rect = null, DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return Rectangle.Empty;
            Dimension bounds = rect ?? dummy;

            var len = length ?? text.Length;
            var flag = flags.getMeasureFlag(false);

            var i = DrawText(hdc, text, len, ref bounds, (int)flag);

            return bounds;
        }

        static bool Measure(this IntPtr hdc, string text, out Rectangle[] rectangles, Point p,
            int? length = null, Rectangle? rect = null,  DrawTextFlags? flags = null)
        {
            rectangles = new Rectangle[2];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return true;
            Dimension bounds = rect ?? dummy;

            var len = length ?? text.Length;
            var flag = flags.getMeasureFlag(false);

            Rectangle rc, rc1;
            rc1 = hdc.charBound(text, len, ref bounds, (int)flag, out rc);
            rectangles = new Rectangle[] { rc1, rc };
            return (rectangles[0].Left < bounds.Left || rectangles[0].Has(p.X));
        }

        static bool Has(this Rectangle rect, int x = -1,
            int y = -1, int checkRightUpto = -1, int checkBottomUpto = -1)
        {
            if (x == -1 && y == -1)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x == -1 ? rect.X : x;
                y = y == -1 ? rect.Y : y;
            }
            if (checkRightUpto == -1)
            {
                checkRightUpto = rect.Width;
            }
            if (checkBottomUpto == -1)
            {
                checkBottomUpto = rect.Height;
            }
            return x >= rect.Left && x <= rect.Left +
                checkRightUpto && y >= rect.Top &&
                y <= rect.Top + checkBottomUpto;
        }

        static bool Has(this Rectangle rect, Point p,
           int checkRightUpto = -1, int checkBottomUpto = -1)
        {
            return rect.Has(p.X, p.Y, checkRightUpto, checkBottomUpto);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    #region structs
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Dimension
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

        public Dimension(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }
        public Dimension(Rectangle r)
        {
            this.Left = r.Left;
            this.Top = r.Top;
            this.Bottom = r.Bottom;
            this.Right = r.Right;
        }
        public static implicit operator Rectangle(Dimension rc)
        {
            return Rectangle.FromLTRB(rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Right, rc.Bottom);
        }
        public static implicit operator Dimension(Rectangle rc)
        {
            return new Dimension(rc);
        }

        public static Dimension Default
        {
            get { return new Dimension(0, 0, 1, 1); }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Trivertex
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public ushort Red;
        public ushort Green;
        public ushort Blue;
        public ushort Alpha;

        public Trivertex(int x, int y, Color color)
            : this(x, y, color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A)
        {
        }
        public Trivertex(int x, int y, Color color, Color other)
            : this(x, y, color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A, other)
        {
        }
        public Trivertex(int x, int y, ushort red, ushort green, ushort blue, ushort alpha)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            Red = (ushort)(red << 8);
            Green = (ushort)(green << 8);
            Blue = (ushort)(blue << 8);
            Alpha = (ushort)(alpha << 8);
        }
        public Trivertex(int x, int y, ushort red, ushort green, ushort blue, ushort alpha, Color other)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            Red = (ushort)((red + other.R / 2) << 8);
            Green = (ushort)((green + other.G / 2) << 8);
            Blue = (ushort)((blue + other.B / 2) << 8);
            Alpha = (ushort)((alpha + other.A / 2) << 8);
        }

        public static ushort R(Color c)
        {
            return (ushort)(c.R << 8);
        }
        public static ushort G(Color c)
        {
            return (ushort)(c.G << 8);
        }
        public static ushort B(Color c)
        {
            return (ushort)(c.B << 8);
        }
        public static ushort R(Color c, Color c1)
        {
            return (ushort)(((c.R + c1.R / 2)) << 8);
        }
        public static ushort G(Color c, Color c1)
        {
            return (ushort)(((c.G + c1.G / 2)) << 8);
        }
        public static ushort B(Color c, Color c1)
        {
            return (ushort)(((c.B + c1.B / 2)) << 8);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region textmeasurement interface + class
    public interface ITextMeasurement : ICloneable
    {
        int CharIndex { get; set; }
        int PreviousIndex { get; }
        Rectangle Bounds { get; }
        Rectangle TextBounds { get; }
        char Char { get; }
        Point UserPoint { get; }

        void CopyFrom(ITextMeasurement other);
    }
    public class TextMeasurement : ITextMeasurement
    {
        Rectangle now, textBound;

        public virtual Rectangle Bounds
        {
            get
            {
                return now;
            }
            set { now = value; }
        }
        public virtual Rectangle TextBounds
        {
            get
            {
                return textBound; ;
            }
            set { textBound = value; }
        }

        public virtual int CharIndex { get; set; }
        public virtual int PreviousIndex { get; set; }
        public virtual char Char { get; set; }
        public Point UserPoint { get; set; }

        public virtual void CopyFrom(ITextMeasurement tm)
        {
            PreviousIndex = tm.PreviousIndex;
            CharIndex = tm.CharIndex;
            Bounds = tm.Bounds;
            Char = tm.Char;
            TextBounds = tm.TextBounds;
            UserPoint = tm.UserPoint;
            if (UserPoint.IsEmpty) UserPoint = Bounds.Location;
        }
        public virtual object Clone()
        {
            var tm = new TextMeasurement();
            tm.CopyFrom(this);
            return tm;
        }
        protected virtual void ResetBounds(Point p)
        {
            ResetBounds(p.X, p.Y);
        }
        protected virtual void ResetBounds(int? lineX = null, int? lineY = null)
        {
            if (lineX.HasValue)
            {
                now.X = lineX.Value;
                textBound.X = lineX.Value;
            }
            if (lineY.HasValue)
            {
                now.Y = lineY.Value;
                textBound.Y = lineY.Value;
            }
        }
        protected virtual void ResetEmptyBounds(Rectangle rc)
        {
            now = rc;
            textBound = rc;
        }
        public static TextMeasurement Default
        {
            get { return new TextMeasurement(); }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region enums
    public enum DrawTextFlags
    {
        CalculateArea = 0x00000400,
        WordBreak = 0x00000010,
        TextBoxControl = 0x00002000,
        Top = 0x00000000,
        Left = 0x00000000,
        HorizontalCenter = 0x00000001,
        Right = 0x00000002,
        VerticalCenter = 0x00000004,
        Bottom = 0x00000008,
        SingleLine = 0x00000020,
        ExpandTabs = 0x00000040,
        TabStop = 0x00000080,
        NoClipping = 0x00000100,
        ExternalLeading = 0x00000200,
        NoPrefix = 0x00000800,
        Internal = 0x00001000,
        PathEllipsis = 0x00004000,
        EndEllipsis = 0x00008000,
        WordEllipsis = 0x00040000,
        ModifyString = 0x00010000,
        RightToLeft = 0x00020000,
        NoFullWidthCharacterBreak = 0x00080000,
        HidePrefix = 0x00100000,
        PrefixOnly = 0x00200000,
        NoPadding = 0x10000000,
    }
    public enum Angle
    {
        A0 = 0,
        A45 = 45,
        A90 = 90,
        A135 = 135,
        A180 = 180
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Suppose your ItemText at index 2 is "StackOverFlow is a wonderful site" and you want to highlight "StackOverFlow" then your startIndex =0 and endIndex = 12.

To highlight portion of text use HighlightItemText method:

```
listBox.HilightItemText(2, 0, 12, Color.Black, Color.Gold, Color.Yellow);
```

To get highlighted coordinates use GetPortionRectangleToHighlight method to get co-ordinates of text portion to highlight. Please note that you just need to pass start and end index as well of portion text.

so call the function like:

```
var portionRectangle = listBox1.GetPortionRectangleToHighlight (2, 0, 12);
```

Have a look at the attached image as working proof of concept.
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I am well aware of the point-of-no-return regarding things like "right-to-left, caret positioning, non-fixed fonts etc.".  This is thankfully "simpler" than that and I wouldn't even attempt this if I had to deal with those cases.  I will try what you have suggested here and let you know.

Comment: @Patrick, I have edited rangeBound method so please modify it accordingly at your end otherwise the code won't work and it will waste your time. I have changed textBound=Rectangle.Empty to  textBound =hdc.textBound(text, container, flags);

Comment: I just came on here to comment that I'm failing in the static Rectangle rangeBound method!  I'll modify it, thanks!

Comment: Wow, so close with the functions you provided.  I have now also added the capability to loop through multiple occurrences, and after that fix you just provided, it does run through without error, and looks close.  Close, but not quite.  Any idea why this would be?  http://i.imgur.com/yw7Zqtn.png

Comment: Success! I made some modifications. There is some overlapping of the highlighted areas, and a lower case issue ... but I'll work through unless you have any quick tips, but otherwise, thanks!  Results as they are now, including highlighting multiple occurrences: http://i.imgur.com/sKec5sA.png

Comment: @Patrick which method you are using to render text? If you are using TextRender.DrawText then stop using it and use DrawText instead which is there in my code snippet. Golden rule is use the same method to measure and draw text. Don't mix them and you get rid of the final overlapping problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110914/discussion-between-mukesh-adhvaryu-and-patrick).

Comment: I have published the demo project on GitHub after including functionality of drawing text as well. [HilightText](https://github.com/MukeshAdhvaryu/HighLightText)

Comment: I am using `TextRenderer.DrawText`.  I see the DllImport but do you have a simplified version without all the parameters you are using to call it internally?  You can see how I call `DrawText` in the initial post.  I am unsure how to convert that to the required parameters such as `lpStr`, `nCount`,  `wFormat`, etc).

Comment: @Patrik see my last comment which points to GitHub repository. Download source code. It has HilightText method. Meanwhile,  lpstr =your text, nccount=length of  text, wformat =0 in your case. lprect =your itemrectangle converted to Dimension struct like this: Dimension dm = your itemrectangle

Comment: @Patrik ok I am going to edit my answer so that now Helper class will have HighlightText method which you can use directly.

Comment: @Patrick I have edited my answer now so that you can use DrawText directly on your listbox. Please mark my answer as accepted once you get what you want with this.

Comment: This works flawlessly, thank you!  I pulled your GitHub project and then broke it a part a bit to fit my needs (internalizing some of the methods that took in "this ListBox" directly into my derived ColoredListBox control, as private methods.  Left the other stuff in a generalized GDI.Tools project.  Otherwise, everything works as expected.  Love the color transition effect too!  Thanks.  Output now:  http://i.imgur.com/VFdMriB.png

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be something like this:

```
    private string[] _sentences = {
        "Old height on pictureOne: 766",
        "New height on pictureOne: 900",
        "",
        "Forcing width on objectX"
    };

    private void Form1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        int y = 10; //Start position
        int x;

        foreach (string s in _sentences) {
            x = 0; //Start position
            foreach (string word in s.Split(' ')) {
                if (ShouldHeighlightWord(word)) {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(word + " ", this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), x, y);
                }
                else {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(word + " ", this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x, y);
                }
                x += (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(word + " ", this.Font).Width;
            }

            y += (int)Math.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString("I", this.Font).Height);
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldHeighlightWord(string word) {
        switch (word) {
            case "on":
            case "Old":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

This code is just drawing the strings onto an empty form and instead of highlighting it just changes the color to Red.

But i think you understand what i mean.
Since i dont have more code its hard to make a better example for you.

When you check:

```
if (SomethingToHighlight(item)) {
```

That only returns true/false i guess and you need something that returns all words to be highlighted, but since a word can occur twice (or more) in one sentence you need to be able to get a position in the string as well. Or just take one word at a time and check if it should be highlighted or not and then draw it to the control.

Comment: This won't work.  I simplified your example down by removing looping through the entire sentence, so it just tries it with a single word.  In the example, on the first pass, if it finds a word to highlight it is going to put it at X, Y of 0, 10 without any logic behind that (those being the default values for the first pass).

It's more complex than this.  It needs to know the X, Y coordinates of the matching word that it found in the `ListItem` object, and then draw OVER that specific area with the highlight. I just can't determine how to place it correctly in the X direction.

Comment: Since you first draw the string on the correct location using fullMessageRect you can just set that as the start point for x and y ?

Comment: My current attack at this is to split up the string as you suggested, determine if the particular area needs to be highlighted, and then draw it one way or the other.  Unfortunately, I can't use space as a delimiter (or anything else).  "SomethingChangedHeight" and "(Height) was Changed" have to both have "Height" highlighted.  Which seems to require to do this one character at a time.  There must be a better way.